# Updating swt ui from another thread every second

Tags: java, swt, ui-thread

I am working on a SWT java project for MAC OS, i need to add a label on SWT UI where i have to show the current time, updating on every second. I tried it i.e.

```
final Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(composite, SWT.CENTER);
FormData fd_lblNewLabel_1 = new FormData();
fd_lblNewLabel_1.left = new FormAttachment(btnNewButton_call, 10);
fd_lblNewLabel_1.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
fd_lblNewLabel_1.right = new FormAttachment(btnTransfer, -10);
fd_lblNewLabel_1.height = 20;
lblNewLabel_1.setLayoutData(fd_lblNewLabel_1);
    getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    lblNewLabel_1.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }   
            }
        });
```

but its not working, please help me do that.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not updating the UI from another thread - you're updating the UI thread from itself.

`sleep`ing on the UI thread will prevent the UI thread from doing things like painting, so it will appear that your program has hung.

Instead of schedule the UI thread to run a `Runnable` that updates a widget and sleeps for a second, you want a thread that sleeps every second and then schedules a `Runnable` that updates the widget *and then exits quickly*.

For example:

```
while(true)
{
    getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        lblNewLabel_1.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
    });

    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Better use `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.timerExec(int, Runnable)` method to update UI on timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

I did it exactly..using following code

```
Thread timeThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    display.syncExec(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            lblNewLabel_1.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        timeThread.setDaemon(true);
        timeThread.start();
```

Comment: Looks like you used the approach from @EdwardThomson. You should upvote and accept his answer then...

Comment: I have accepted his answer but cant up-vote because for that minimum 15 reputation required.

Comment: Now you have 15 reputation ;)

Comment: @Mukesh Kumar: Sambi reddys answer is more appropriate.

Comment: I don't think so, because when i used that method that run only one time not periodical. i called that i.e.`display.timerExec(1000, new Runnable() {
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
     lblNewLabel_1.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
     
    }
   });`